# Use the data frame which name is stored in variable

Tags: r

I am trying to create function with two arguments - data frame name and column name. The functions objective is to convert dates with format yymmdd (integer, eg. 930820) into date format in r (e.g. 1993-08-20)

```
chng.dts <- function(df, col) {
    as.Date(
        paste0(
            ifelse(as.numeric(substr(df$col, 1, 2)) > 20, 1900, 2000)
            + as.numeric(substr(df$col,1,2)),'-'
             ,substr(df$col,3,4),'-'
             ,substr(df$col,5,6)
        )
    )
}
```

Of course I know I can't type df$col in the function, but I would like to know how is it possible to refer to column 'col' in data frame 'df' inside the function.

As far as I lurked the Stack Overflow I only found that if column is variable and data frame is not, then it can be solved by typing

```
df[[col]]
```

But I need to refer to variable data frame name as well.

Comment: You can use `get(df)` if `df` is a string whose symbol refers to a `data.frame`, but I'm not sure why you would want to pass a string in your example, rather than supplying the actual `data.frame`.

Comment: If the data frame is passed in to your function, like `chng.dts(df = my_data, ...)`, then inside your function you call the data frame `df`. As Renu says, you only need `get` if a string is passed in, like `chng.dts(df = "my_data", ...)`. I think your only problem is that you need to `return(df)` at the end of your function and assign the result to update your data, `my_data = chng.dts(my_data, col = "column_name")`.